# WordPress - Only show authors with posts

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to list all of the authors in my wordpress blog that have published posts, excluding the admin.  The below works for excluding the admin but when I add "AND post_count > 0" to only show authors with posts it doesn't display anything.  Is there a way to modify this code to only show authors with posts?

```
function contributors() { 
global $wpdb;
$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE display_name <> 'admin' AND post_count > 0 ORDER BY display_name");

foreach ($authors as $author ) {

echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
echo "/\">";
echo get_avatar($author->ID, 12);
echo "</a>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
echo "/\">";
the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
echo "</a>";
echo "</li>";
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: Figured it out.

I added the following function:

    $post_count = get_usernumposts($author->ID);

And then add an if statement around the output like so:

    if($post_count > 0){

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, 
    user_nicename, 
    (select count(*) from wp_posts where post_author=w.ID) as posts 
FROM wp_users w 
WHERE display_name <> 'admin' 
ORDER BY display_name) as final WHERE posts>0
```